# Infinite loop? Java error

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am attempting to write code that takes the number of sides of a polygon and the length of each side as input and gives the area of the polygon as output. The JRE I am using says that my code will not run, possibly because of an endless loop. I do not see any errors in my code, but I have an untrained eye so any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise04_05{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of sides: ");
        double num = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the side: ");
        double side = input.nextInt();

        double area = (num*side*side) / (4 * Math.tan(Math.PI / num));

        System.out.print("the area of the polygon is: " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error it is showing

Comment: Builds and runs fine for me. I say your JDK is drunk, but you'd need to provide more information about how you are compiling and running the code and copy and paste the actual error (in full) before we could be sure

Comment: "The JRE I am using says that my code will not run, possibly because of an endless loop" --> Post the **exact** message that you're getting.

Comment: This code compiles and runs fine.  Could you please provide exact jre message?

Comment: I was using Eclipse on my computer but it kept crashing, so I used online compiler J Doodle. This site simply says "Timeout - your program may have an infinite loop" I wrote the code for an assignment for my class and when I submit it, it says unexpected output. These two combines is what led me to believe it was an infinite loop

Comment: You probably need to supply some input in the "Stdin Inputs" field on JDoodle. Your program will block until the Scanner object has read two integers.

Comment: Couple of fun things to think about - what happens if num <= 2? What happens if side <= 0? Does a fractional number of sides make sense? What happens if you use input.nextDouble() instead of input.nextInt()?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler accepts standard input in the Stdin Inputs field. If you don't provide any input then the program will wait for a short amount of time before JDoodle kills it with the following output:

```
Enter the number of sides: 


 JDoodle - Timeout -  Some common reasons for Timeout 
Your Program may have a endless loop 
Please check the program and try again or contact JDoodle support at jdoodle@nutpan.com for more info.
```

Your error message will go away when you add the right number of inputs. They can be space-separated or newline-separated.

Answer (score 0):

i am simply works on the code you did just change class name.here is my code..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class New{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of sides: ");
        double num = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the side: ");
        double side = input.nextInt();

        double area = (num*side*side) / (4 * Math.tan(Math.PI / num));

        System.out.print("the area of the polygon is: " + area);
    }
}
```